# SSL certificate mismatch within home network

Tags: dns, port-forwarding, ssl-certificate, letsencrypt

I use Home Automation to control my heating, lights etc.

I installed a letsencrypt cert and I use a custom domain name to access it securely.

https://home.mydomain.tld/

This uses port 443 natively.

More recently I used letsencrypt to install another cert on my Ubiquity ER-X router so that I can also access it securely.

(It also uses port 443 natively, so I set up a port forward from 7575 to 443.)

https://router.mydomain.tld:7575/

Everything works perfectly from all devices within my network — and from outside of my network — with one exception.

I've directed the Home Assistant app to home.mydomain.tld. When used externally, fine. But when when used from *within* my network it instead picks up the cert for router.mydomain.tld.

```
TrafficStats: tagSocket(236) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
chromium: [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
WebviewActivity: onReceivedSslError: primary error: 2 certificate: Issued to: CN=router.mydomain.tld;
WebviewActivity: Issued by: CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US;
WebviewActivity:  on URL: https://home.mydomain.tld/?external_auth=1
```

I have no clue how to segregate the two. Any ideas?

(I have a feeling the answer will be to set up a reverse-proxy. I'm open to that idea, but hoping there is a simpler solution.)

Comment: how are you handling naming (DNS) for your setup? I'm assuming you have registered a domain publicly (for your external access), do you have an internal DNS server for your LAN? your router probably supports Hairpinning (so it can be configured to let LAN clients use the public IP), but that you have two services on 443 that are ambiguous for certain interfaces is tricky to handle. if you have an internal DNS service though, you could point  https://home.mydomain.tld/ to its LAN IP, and prevent the traffic from going to the router at all.